# Dynamically add dimension to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I thought about it a lot before posting this question.

The question is more conceptual than anything else.

Starting from a classic array, I want to **dynamically** transform it into multidinamic with subtrees.

to be clear, from this:

```
$array = ['my', 'unique', 'values', 'array', 'and', 'so', 'on', '...'];
```

to this:

```
Array
(
    ['my'] =>
        ['unique'] =>
            ['values'] =>
                ['array'] =>
                    ['and'] =>
                        ['so'] =>
                            ['on']=>
                                ['...'] => []
)
```

The only attempt I made was "barbarously" to dynamically create strings and pass them with the `eval()` command.

I don't write the code here for personal dignity. It's bad enough I confessed it. Insiders will understand...

I fully believe that there is a correct way to do it, but of course, if I'm here, I don't know it

Best

Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from the end and end with the start:

```
$length = sizeof($array);
$value = [];
for ($index = $length - 1; $index >= 0; $index--) {
    $value = [
        "{$array[$index]}" => $value
    ];
    unset($array[$index]);
}
$array[]=$value;
```

Comment: Vote up without needing to test the code. It was enough for me to have read it. Low level code, as I like it. More than "thank you", I congratulate you !!!

Comment: You don't really need the `unset()`, just overwrite the array at the end - `$array=$value;`

Answer (score 4):

This uses references to keep track of what element you are currently adding the data to, so to start `$add` is the root element (by setting it to `&$newArray`).  Each time it adds a new level it moves the reference to this new item (with `&$add[$key]`) and repeats the process...

```
$array = ['my', 'unique', 'values', 'array', 'and', 'so', 'on', '...'];
$newArray = [];
$add = &$newArray;
foreach ( $array as $key )  {
    $add[$key] = [];
    $add = &$add[$key];
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: I realize to be a duffer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Or another option is to create the structure from the outside in using a while loop and decreasing the index on every iteration.

Temporary store what you already have and reset the current `$result`. Then add an entry with a new key and add the temporary stored variable as the value.

```
$array = ['my', 'unique', 'values', 'array', 'and', 'so', 'on'];
$result = [];
$tot = count($array) - 1;

while ($tot > -1) {
    $temp = $result;
    $result = [];
    $result[$array[$tot]] = $temp;
    $tot--;
}

print_r($result);
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/dUNmU)